# How to print sale invoice for inventory system

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I want to know how to print data received from a database table in a WPF application.

I have done an inventory system for a supper market, but I can't complete this without completing sale invoice printing part.

Can you help me?

Comment: the scope is too vast for the question to be answered, try out yourself something and  come back when you have practical problem that  you have in coding

Comment: How do you think people can help you without providing any information about your work? Please give people more information. Try yourself first.

Comment: there are so many ways for different needs and situations such that the overall answer to your question could be a medium size book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PrintDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to print an instance of a [`DocumentPaginator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can get a `DocumentPaginator` from a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
FlowDocument document = ...
flowDocumentPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator;

var dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintDocument(flowDocumentPaginator, "Your description");
```

So basically, all you have to do is create a `FlowDocument` and add a [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to it with the data from your database.

Here's some code to get you started with the `FlowDocument`:

```
var document = new FlowDocument();
document.PagePadding = new Thickness(20, 60, 20, 20);
document.ColumnGap = 0;
var table = new Table();
table.CellSpacing = 0;

var quantityColumn = new TableColumn();
quantityColumn.Width = new GridLength(80);
var priceColumn = new TableColumn();
priceColumn .Width = new GridLength(80);
var textColumn = new TableColumn();
textColumn.Width = new GridLength(500);

table.Columns.Add(quantityColumn);
table.Columns.Add(priceColumn);
table.Columns.Add(textColumn);

var rowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
table.RowGroups.Add(rowGroup);

foreach (var item in yourData)
{
    //Add your data
    var itemRow = new TableRow();

    //Assuming your data item has Quantity, Price and Text
    itemRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(item.Quantity.ToString()))));
    itemRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(item.Price.ToString()))));
    itemRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(item.Text))));
    //Etc.
}

document.Blocks.Add(table);
```